# AQM Broadcast Early WTD COUNTERS

Tags: cisco-catalyst, qos

The command "show platform qos queue stats gigabitEthernet X" yields the following output on a Catalyst 3850 switch:

```
...
AQM Broadcast Early WTD COUNTERS(In terms of Bytes)
--------------------------------------------------
  PORT TYPE          ENQUEUE             DROP
--------------------------------------------------
 UPLINK PORT-0        N/A               0
 UPLINK PORT-1        N/A               0
 UPLINK PORT-2        N/A               0
 UPLINK PORT-3        N/A               0
 NETWORK PORTS  678938231502        678938231502
 RCP PORTS               0                  0
 CPU PORT                0                  0
```

What exactly does "NETWORK PORTS" represent, and why is the traffic being dropped? The counters enumerate each time I issue the command.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

See [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst3850/software/release/3se/qos/configuration_guide/b_qos_3se_3850_cg/b_qos_3se_3850_cg_chapter_011.html#concept_C0D82F44D8964628B78EBA62CCF27724)

WTD = Weighted Tail Drop

AQM = Advanced Queue Management (I think)

Network Ports = "downlink ports" i.e. non-uplink ports

Translation: The 3850 is marking some traffic headed out of one or more downlink ports for tail drop

Comment: Are these really broadcast drops or would this counter also include unicast traffic?

Comment: @PaulGarrett Unfortunately the documentation does not clarify that, so you would have to find that out independently (using netflow, the output of show interfaces, the qos policies if any, etc.